# How to change Wiki JS favicon deployed in Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, wiki

I have a Wiki JS container running in Azure Web App (followed this doc: https://docs.requarks.io/install/azurewebapp), and I want to change the favicon. I read that maybe I can overwrite the favicon mount in the Azure Web App configuration, but unfortunately that's not working for now. Here's what I did so far:

Azure Web App - Path mappings

[image: Azure Web App - Path mappings]

Azure Storage - Fileshare

[image: Azure Storage - Fileshare]

Wiki JS - Uploaded favicon

[image: Wiki JS - Uploaded favicon]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `wiki.js` but if this is not the default path where the favicon file is present, you will also need to [change in the main HTML file](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_favicon.asp). Also, according to [this comment](https://github.com/Requarks/wiki/issues/1854#issuecomment-625646213), the paths might be different when using the container.

Since you are using a container, another option would be to build [your own container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-custom-container) with your customizations and use that in your Web App.